# The Wizards Riddle

Tags: riddle

I made a short riddle this morning and thought I'd share it here.

> My job is my name,
>   But I have no brain,
>   I stand all alone,
>   Yet no legs I own.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like

> A scarecrow.

My job is my name

> It scares crows.

But I have no brain

> In The Wizard of Oz, the Scarecrow needs a brain.

I stand all alone

> In a crop field.

Yet no legs I own

> Scarecrows are hung on a cross.

And the title refers to

> The character in The Wizard of Oz.

Comment: Congratulations. I thought it was simple yet amusing, though I haven't gotten any answers back from my team at work yet.

Comment: Huh, I thought the "I have no brain" line was a big red flag. I hope nobody at your work thought that that line was directed at them!

Comment: I get that this was the intended answer, but the clues fit quite a lot more things, container, for example.

Comment: I got confused at "Yet no legs I own" as for every depiction I have seen they do own legs.

Comment: @ThomasMoors - Sorry about that, the answer certainly is a little debatable. Especially because the character referred to in the reference actually _did_ have legs, [although many don't](http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/crow1.jpg).